# Question on Rudin's Theorem 2.38: can any of the $I_n$ be empty?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Theorem 2.38 in Rudin says the following:

> If $\{I_n\}$ is a sequence of intervals in $\mathbb{R}^1$, such that $I_n \supset I_{n+1}$ ($n=1,2,3, \ldots$), then $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n I_n$ is not empty.

My first difficulty is that in the proof he only considered closed intervals. I don't think the result holds in the case of open intervals, e.g., $I_n = \left(0, \frac{1}{n}\right)$, so I think by "interval" he means "closed, bounded interval," i.e., something of the form $[a,b]$. Is this a correct interpretation?

Second, if one of the $I_n$ is allowed to be empty, this theorem breaks. If $I_n = \emptyset$ for some $n$, then I'd need $\emptyset \supset I_{n+1}$, meaning $I_{m} = \emptyset$ for all $m > n$. I could take $I_n = \emptyset$ for every $n$, and it seems to, strictly speaking, satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem but have empty intersection. Then again, though $\emptyset$ is an interval, say $(a,a)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, it isn't a closed interval of the form $[a,b]$. Is that the distinction?

Comment: Yes, you need closed intervals for this theorem and closed intervals cannot be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My first difficulty is that in the proof he only considered closed intervals. I don't think the result holds in the case of open intervals, e.g., $I_n = \left(0, \frac{1}{n}\right)$, so I think by "interval" he means "closed, bounded interval," i.e., something of the form $[a,b]$. Is this a correct interpretation?

Correct. In fact, Rudin notes this in Definition $2.17$. He makes a distinction between the ***segment*** $(a,b)$ and the ***interval*** $[a,b]$ - that is, segments are open and intervals are closed.

Rudin does neglect to mention the possible cases where $a,b$ are possibly infinite (to address the "bounded" interval claim), though a definition terminology is sometimes used for those -- I have often seen ***ray*** for $[a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b]$ or their open versions, for instance.

Boundedness is however necessary (if one allows Rudin's definition to be about "infinite intervals" such as the above): consider the case of
$
I_n := [ n , \infty)
$
to see why. (Hence, as is typical, Rudin is implicitly assuming $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and, as we'll see, $a<b$ or $a\le b$ as needed.)

---

> Second, if one of the $I_n$ is allowed to be empty, this theorem breaks. If $I_n = \emptyset$ for some $n$, then I'd need $\emptyset \supset I_{n+1}$, meaning $I_{m} = \emptyset$ for all $m > n$. I could take $I_n = \emptyset$ for every $n$, and it seems to, strictly speaking, satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem but have empty intersection. Then again, though $\emptyset$ is an interval, say $(a,a)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, it isn't a closed interval of the form $[a,b]$. Is that the distinction?

Yes, technically speaking, $(a,b) = \emptyset$ if $a \ge b$, and $[a,b] = \emptyset$ if $a>b$, if we simply define them via the rules
$$\begin{align*}
(a,b) &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < x < b \} \\
[a,b] &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a \le x \le b \} 
\end{align*}$$
and so typically it is required that $a<b$ or $a\le b$ to define an interval in the first place, even if Rudin chooses not to. (Hence, in that sense, the empty set or a singleton could be considered as "degenerate" intervals, since they would break things or result in uninteresting conclusions.)

Hence, yes, strictly speaking, Rudin should be specifying in some way that the intervals are nonempty (be it in the theorem, or in his definition of intervals).

I will note again it is mostly a nitpicky issue that falls in the realm of "technically correct", since most people don't really care about the empty set or singletons as degenerate intervals anyways, though, and when defining $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ are already on some level assuming the appropriate ordering of $a,b$ to make them nonempty/non-singletons.